# How to check if VlcMedia contains a video?

Tags: c++, qt, libvlc, vlc-qt

I am developing a media player using `vlc-qt` I wanted to know how can I identify that my player contains a video or not.
For example

```
m_player=new VlcMediaPlayer(m_instance);
m_media= new VlcMedia("",m_instance);
m_player->open(m_media);
m_player->play()
```

As you can see here my `m_media` is initialized with no video url so how can I check whether my `m_media` contains any video or not.

I wanted to know this because so that in my player i will control  `play/stop` button.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

After opening the media use [VlcMediaPlayer::video](https://vlc-qt.tano.si/reference/1.1/classvlcmediaplayer#ad44558c90f9b0e5374b5ba9ac07867ec) to retrieve the video object and check if it is valid, i.e. not a `nullptr`.

### Example

Here is an example I wrote for you to demonstrate a possible implementation of the proposed solution:

```
m_player = new VlcMediaPlayer(m_instance);
m_media = new VlcMedia("", m_instance);
m_player->open(m_media);

if (m_player->video())
    m_player->play();
```

Comment: Not helpful ```m_player->video()``` returning some unknown number. For example if I initialized the ```m_media``` like ```m_media=new VlcMedia("",m_instance)``` the value returned by ```qDebug()<<m_player->video()``` I getting is ``` 0x56080a15acd0 ```. Please test your code and let me know.

Comment: @VinayKumarShukla, What you get is not _some unknown number_, but the address of the `VlcVideo` object. If there is an adress, there is an object. If the address is 0, there is no object.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt/blob/9b2f561dd8e2a3508d80c703eb0be5d8b82c05ec/src/core/MediaPlayer.cpp), the video object is initialized in the constructor of `VlcMediaPlayer`. It doesn't indicate the availability of the actual video.

Comment: @NgocMinhNguyen, you are right. I thought about using [`VlcMediaPlayer::error`](https://vlc-qt.tano.si/reference/1.1/classvlcmediaplayer#a1962600a911755302a907f80c71895f3) signal as indicator. Unfortunatelly, now I do not have time to test it. You might use it in your answer if you wish.

Comment: @scopchanov even if I just initialize it with double quotes (means with no video) like ```m_media= new VlcMedia("",m_instance)``` still it will give me some address not 0.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`VlcMedia` source](https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt/blob/9b2f561dd8e2a3508d80c703eb0be5d8b82c05ec/src/core/Media.cpp#134), the string you give to the class can be retrieved using the getter `VlcMedia::currentLocation()`. From that string, you can use `QFile::exists()` to check if the file path exists.

Comment: What if the media is not local?

Comment: That's true. I haven't thought of it.